# How to build an Array in ruby from a yielding function

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a better way for

```
result = []
function_that_yields{ |value| result << value }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the function that yields has no logic to build the array, then this is the only way to accomplish this task.
Otherwise, consider using built-in enumerable methods such as [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003129) or [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003128).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use 
result = something.inject([]) {|x,y| x << y}

You can push anything into x, so you could do something like x << value in this case.